# Laravel8 - after insert using Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, forms

Hello every one I'm using laravel8 and using Ajax to insert records in database.
my problem is that after I insert record ,then it automatically goes to new page but it just contains an response as json object(screenshot of page below)

How can I prevent that and redirect in normal way.

my controller code :

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $user = User::create($request->all());
        return response()->json(['url'=>url('/users')]);
}
```

my view :

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{route('users.store')}}",
            data:{
             name:        $("#name").val(),
             email :      $("#email").val(),
             image :  $("#image").val(),
            },
             success: function(response){

                 if(response){
                $("#userTable tbody").prepend(
                    '<tr><td>'+ response.id+'</td><td>'
                     + response.name+'</td><td>',
                     + response.email+'</td><td>',
                     + response.image+'</td><td>'
            )
              window.location.href=response.url;

                     $("#userForm")[0].reset();
                $("#userModel").model('hide');

            }
```

here is the page

[image]

sorry for my bad english

Comment: What does your route and controller/method for `/users` look like? You're redirecting there

Comment: here is route:
Route::get('/users', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');

here is method :
 public function index(){

        $users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return view('users.index',compact('users'));

    }

Comment: So if you are trying to send a post request to server to create a new User and then once the user is created you are trying to show the index page, why do you need to do an ajax request. You can make a simple post request to the server to create a new user and then redirect to the index page

Comment: I did't understand you will , so what I need to do after store , its always give me a new page with json array after insert using Ajax

Comment: most probably the response.url contains the json stored in url key, try to so response.url.url, so that you get the string, `window.location.href=response.url.url;`

Comment: I have form and list of users in the same page

Comment: I'm sorry but still have the same problem , help me please

Comment: try to show console.log() of response, try to show typeof response.url is it a string, also use @with username as well, otherwise that user does not get notification of any new message

Comment: I have this error in console 
content.js:48 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.engines is not iterable
    at E.updateSocialMedia (content.js:48)
    at new E (content.js:48)
    at Function.start (content.js:48)
    at Function.main (content.js:48)

Comment: what is giving this error console.log(response); what is on line 48 you can check by clicking on it it will move on to sources tab

Comment: this error is related to Mcafee extention I stoped it , but if I write 
 success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
             window.location.href=response.url;
nothing appear in console

Comment: comment window.location to prevent redirecting console will be in the page which calls ajax request

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here `return response()->json(['url'=>url('/users')]);`

You can just return per example `return response()->json(data);`

Here's an example :

#### Controller :

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $user = User::create($request->all());
        $data = collect();
        
        //TODO: find a way to catch user data you created
 
        $data->push([
           'email' => (your attribute),
           'name' => (your attribute),
           'image' => (your attribute),
           'id' => (your attribute),
           'url' => (your url),
        ]);

        return response()->json($data);

}
```

#### Ajax :

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{route('users.store')}}",
            data:{
             name:        $("#name").val(),
             email :      $("#email").val(),
             image :  $("#image").val(),
            },
             success: function(data){

                 if(data){
                $("#userTable tbody").prepend(
                    '<tr><td>'+ data.id+'</td><td>'
                     + data.name+'</td><td>',
                     + data.email+'</td><td>',
                     + data.image+'</td><td>'
            )
              window.location.href=data.url;

                     $("#userForm")[0].reset();
                $("#userModel").model('hide');

            }
```

Comment: still have the same problem and the page get this data :
[
{
email: "ttt",
name: "tt",
image: { },
id: null,
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users"
}
]

Comment: What do you want to do exactly, I barely understand the result you wanna obtain, show me your routes and all the functions you use in the controller

Comment: ok I try to do something like this video : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOySLaUFFJE 

I do the same of this video but after submit form I have pages with json data 

here is controller : public function index(){

        $users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return view('users.index',compact('users'));

    }

   public function store(Request $request){

        $user = User::create($request->all());

        return response()->json(['url'=>url('/users')]);



   }

Comment: here is view
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

Comment: $("userForm").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({    type: "POST", url: "{{route('users.store')}}",
            data:{ name: $("#name").val(), email :      $("#email").val(),
             image :  $("#image").val(), }, success: function(response){
                console.log(response);  window.location.href=response.url;
                 if(response){  $("#userTable tbody").prepend(
                    '<tr><td>'+ response.id+'</td><td>' + response.name+'</td><td>',

Comment: I have this error in console content.js:48 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.engines is not iterable at E.updateSocialMedia (content.js:48) at new E (content.js:48) at Function.start (content.js:48) at Function.main (content.js:48) –

Answer (score 0):

if fetch data one variable then

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $user = User::create($request->all());
        return response()->json($user);
}


$.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('attendance/branchWiseEmployees') }}',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type:"POST",
                data:{branch_id:branch_id,company_id:company_id},
                success:function(data){
                    if(data){
                       
                       
                        
                        $.each(data,function(key,value){
             // $("#user_id").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                        });
 $("#userTable tbody").append(
                    '<tr><td>'+ data.id+'</td><td>'
                     + data.name+'</td><td>',
                     + data.email+'</td><td>',
                     + data.image+'</td><tr>'
            )

                    }
                }
            });
```